# how can i pass variable in php form to another function with arguments in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i tried this in my form

```
<form action="<?php $id=$post->id; echo base_url('index.php/clients/change/$id'); ?>" method="post" >
```

and want the value of $id in function

```
    public function change($id)
    { 
        echo $id;
   }
```

it shows the error trying to get property of non object id.

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/clients/change/<?php echo $id ?>">link</a>

Comment: Use `"` double quotes `"index.php/clients/change/$id"` or concatenation `'index.php/clients/change/' . $id`.

Comment: Please read [ask] and extract a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Property of non object means the `$post` you are sending is not an object, it could be an array check it using `is_object` or `is_array`. Then if it is an array use `$id=$post['id']`

Answer (score 0):

*Your form `action` should be like this :*

use `$post->id` or `$post['id']` (if an array) instead of `$id` with `site_url()` like this :

**Note** : better use `form helper` for forms

```
 <form action="<?=site_url('clients/change/'.$post->id); ?>" method="post" >

 //in case if u have post as an array
 <form action="<?=site_url('clients/change/'.$post['id']); ?>" method="post" >
```

And your method :

```
public function change($id)
{ 
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: i have one doubt.i have small requirement can you please give me suggestion how can i do that..its very useful for me if u can help

Comment: @suresh yes please if i can

Comment: can you please come to this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177327/discussion-between-ranjit-and-wiktor-stribizew